# Why is my app deployed on Heroku has its database reset periodically?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have a very simple web app on Heroku. The app has a sqlite3 database file with some prepopulated data. After I deploy the app, I can insert/delete records through the web app.

Why is it after some time, let's say 10 hours, when I visit my web app again, the modified data seem to have disappeared, and all that shown is the prepopulated ones?

Comment: Does it work when you run your application locally?

Comment: Apparently it works both locally and on the web: I can add/remove records through the html elements. And the correct results are always retrieved and displayed. But the problem is that when I wake up, and check the deployed Heroku app, those changes that I made the night before are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up your question on the internet. The news is not good. As it turns out you can't really use SQLite on heroku. Check [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) under Disk Backed Storage. Unfortunately your probably going to have to change databases. I would suggest PostgreSQL. I use that on heroku with no problems.

Comment: Thanks, I have switched to PostgreSQL.